# Initializing new line character in C language

Tags: c, char

How do I initialize a new line char in C?

For example, to initialize char A:

```
char letter = 'A';
```

How to initialize new line? Like this maybe:

```
char newLine = '0x0A'?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an escape character like this:

```
char letter = '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to you read [New Line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) , It's explain completely \n \r and UNIX EOL and WINDOWS EOL.It's very nice.